# R parallel programming with globally defines S4 classes

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I don't understand how to pass a globally defined class to a cluster generated using the parallel package. I have it working for a function:

```
funs = "testClass"
fun = function(x) testClass(test = x^2)
testClass = function(test) return(test)

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2, outfile='')
parallel::clusterExport(cl = cl, varlist = funs, envir = globalenv())
res <- parallel::parLapply(cl = cl, X = seq_len(10L), fun = fun)
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
res
```

The same approach does not work for a class:

```
funs = "testClass"
fun = function(x) testClass(test = x^2)
testClass = setClass("testClass", slots = c(test = "numeric"))

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2, outfile='')
parallel::clusterExport(cl = cl, varlist = funs, envir = globalenv())
res <- parallel::parLapply(cl = cl, X = seq_len(10L), fun = fun)
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

I know it is possible to put the class and generator function in a package but is there a simpler solution to this problem?

Comment: Your code doesn't work. What are `funs` and `fun`?

Comment: funs and fun are the same for both code chunks. Updated for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining an S4 class actually modifies some hidden metadata objects in your global environment. It's not enough just to copy the generator function to your slave nodes; you have to execute the class definition statement on each node. (Well, you *could* copy those metadata objects over, but that's just asking for trouble.)

```
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2, outfile='')
parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, expr={
    testClass <- setClass("testClass", slots = c(test = "numeric"))
})
res <- parallel::parLapply(cl = cl, X = seq_len(10L), fun = fun)

res

# [[1]]
# An object of class "testClass"
# Slot "test":
# [1] 1
#
# [[2]]
# An object of class "testClass"
# Slot "test":
# [1] 4
# . . .
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. It solves the small example I gave above. It has also helped to solve the more complex problem I was struggling with. I ended up using parallel::clusterCall instead because it allows you to pass variables in.